# WP_list_table display text on column with textarea

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, wordpress

Friends,

I have implemented the extension of WP_list_table PHP class that I use to render my table in the Wordpress site admin plugin. In one of the columns of the WP_list_table I use textarea field for user notes.

```
function column_notes($item){
    return sprintf(
        '<span><textarea id="%s" ></textarea>', $item['ID']
    );
}
```

When the user adds some text in the text area, I save it with javascript and jquery to a WP database table column 'notes'. If I read from the mysql the contents of the 'notes' column with PHP how can I display them on the textarea? In the WP_list_table I use function prepare_items to prepare data for the table. For each item that I want to display in table row I define data array:

```
$data[] =array(
    'ID' => $order->id,
    'date_created' => wc_format_datetime($order->get_date_created()),
    'total'=> wc_price($order->total),
    'notes'=> htmlspecialchars($wpdb->get_var("SELECT notes FROM orders WHERE id = '$order->id'"))
);
```

Although the query returns the contents of the notes field from DB, its not displayed on the text area. Is it possible to do that with php, or do I need javascript/jquery here again?

Comment: The value of a textarea is specified by putting the content _between_ the `textarea` tags. I guess that `$item['notes']` should gives you access to the value in your function there.

Comment: That was easy! thank you bro!